# How can I interpret config documentation examples written in JSON or JavaScript and know how it would translate to YAML?

Tags: javascript, json, yaml, config

For example, the [puppeteer config documentation](https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration) has an example of a configuration file written in JavaScript. There aren't any examples of how to use a YAML file instead. For the sake of conformity, I would like to have all configuration files in my project written in one language. I can convert a JavaSript config to JSON and vice versa without needing documentation, can the same be done with YAML?

Comment: [These are all of the config options](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.configuration). There doesn't seem to be any complex nesting so adding those options to a `.puppeteerrc.yaml` file at the top level should do the trick

Comment: If you can convert to JSON you can already convert to YAML since YAML is a superset of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed this resource on syntax conversion: https://www.json2yaml.com/